# XSL 1.0 - Dynamically choosing set of variables in call-template

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

So I'm transforming an XML feed into HTML and in doing so give the end-user the ability to choose 1 of 3 color schemes. Depending on the color scheme chosen I am trying to assign values to parameters in a call-template command that will render the XML.

I am fairly new to XSL so feel free to point me in a better methodology

Here is an example of my code:

```
<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:variable name="basic_head_title_color">#414141</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="basic_head_title_size">18px</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="basic_head_desc_color">#8b8b8b</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="contrast_head_title_color">#ffffff</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="contrast_head_title_size">18px</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="contrast_head_desc_color">#e1e1e1</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="black_head_title_color">#ffffff</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="black_head_title_size">18px</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="black_head_desc_color">#e1e1e1</xsl:variable>

<xsl:when test="$display_theme = 'basic'" >
    <xsl:variable name ="chosen_head_title_color" select="basic_head_title_color"/>  
    <xsl:variable name ="chosen_head_title_size" select="basic_head_title_size"/>          
    <xsl:variable name ="chosen_head_desc_color" select="basic_head_desc_color"/>                  
</xsl:when>

<xsl:when test="$display_theme = 'contrast'" >
    <xsl:variable name ="chosen_head_title_color" select="contrast_head_title_color"/>  
    <xsl:variable name ="chosen_head_title_size" select="contrast_head_title_size"/>          
    <xsl:variable name ="chosen_head_desc_color" select="contrast_head_desc_color"/>
</xsl:when>

<xsl:when test="$display_theme = 'black'" >
     <xsl:variable name ="chosen_head_title_color" select="black_head_title_color"/>  
    <xsl:variable name ="chosen_head_title_size" select="black_head_title_size"/>          
    <xsl:variable name ="chosen_head_desc_color" select="black_head_desc_color"/>  
</xsl:when>


    <xsl:call-template name="render_xml">
            <xsl:with-param name="head_title_color" select="chosen_head_title_color" />
            <xsl:with-param name="head_title_size" select="chosen_head_title_size" />
            <xsl:with-param name="head_desc_color" select="chosen_head_desc_color" />
    </xsl:call-template>

</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XSLT is invalid in a few places, but how's this?

```
  <xsl:param name="display_theme" select="'basic'" />

  <v:styles xmlns:v="transform-variables">
    <style name="basic" titleColor="#41414" titleSize="18px" descColor="#8b8b8b" />
    <style name="contrast" titleColor="#ffffff" titleSize="18px" descColor="#e1e1e1" />
    <style name="black" titleColor="#ffffff" titleSize="18px" descColor="#e1e1e1" />
  </v:styles>

  <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:variable name="style" select="document('')//style[@name = $display_theme]" />

    <xsl:call-template name="render_xml">
      <xsl:with-param name="head_title_color" select="$style/@titleColor" />
      <xsl:with-param name="head_title_size" select="$style/@titleSize" />
      <xsl:with-param name="head_desc_color" select="$style/@descColor" />
    </xsl:call-template>

  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: This looks Genius, I will attempt to get this functional this afternoon and let you know if it works. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: It worked! Took my code from 936 lines down to 268... Well playd my friend.